# Sudo chown mess up with AWS Credentials and Config

Tags: amazon-web-services, config, sudo, credentials, chown

So, I think I messed up bad. I was having trouble running a python file locally, and during troubleshooting, I read a post that said to run the below:

`sudo chown $(my_username) ~/.aws/credentials                                     sudo chown $(my_username) ~/.aws/config`

I ran that (which presumably changed owner of those files from root to my_username), and now, when I run a python script that utilizes a pyspark session, I'm not able to read in any s3 parquet files!

Is there a way I can revert the ownership of those files back to root? Or is there a way I can just create new ones that root owns and delete the old ones? Am I even thinking about this correctly?

Please help!

Comment: Why don't you  `ls -al ~/.aws` to see what ownership the files have? Then correct as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use braces in bash when doing parameter substitution.

```
sudo chown ${my_username} ~/.aws/credentials
```